# Configure Angular 4 to generate web components

Tags: angular, web-component

For a project I need to provide my code as a `web component`.
[I read that you can configure Angular to generate web components](https://medium.com/@realabhijeet4u/angular-2-0-vs-polymer-f45a4f539238). Plain and simple question: How can that be done?

Comment: do you want to use webcomponent in angular component template?

Comment: A webcomponent is a class with an `@Component` annotation. That's all

Comment: @Maximus no I want to create a web component with Angular

Comment: to be used outside Angular? if yes, you can't. Angular is not a framework for creating a web component. Take a look at polymer

Comment: @PierreDuc Do you have an example? It seems using `@Component` is the normal way to create angular components but how would that create a web component?

Comment: @Maximus are you sure? The Medium post says so

Comment: Yes yes, what I was trying to say is that with the `@Component` you can create a web component which can only be used within angular. Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226449/does-angular2-use-web-components