# Compiling Angular components separate and using them together in an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I created 2 different `Angular` projects in the following way:

```
$ ng new comp-a
$ ng new comp-b
```

Then, I modified each of them to look different and with each of them I ran the following command to build the corresponding `HTML` file with the necessary `Javascript` and `CSS` files:

```
$ ng build --base-href "./"
```

I noticed that on each `index.html` file generated on each project there are referenced the following `Javascript` files:

```
- runtime.js
- polyfills.js
- styles.js
- vendor.js
- main.js
```

**What I want to do:**

Create one common `HTML` file referencing the common files and renaming the non-common files to the component name, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing Angular Components</title>
    <base href="./">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>

<body>

    <comp-a></comp-a>
    <comp-b></comp-b>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="comp-a.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="comp-b.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Requirements of my goal:**

- I need to generate one `Javascript` file per each component.
- I need to use them out of an `Angular` project like in a normal `HTML` page like on the example above. Of course I can add the other common `Javascript` files like on the example above.

Is this possible?

I did a try and didn't work. Maybe, if that's possible, I didn't in the right way. I have to say that I don't have too much experience with Angular.

Thanks!

Comment: if you use angular 6 you should create those 2 components as libraries. The angular6 cli just got support for that.

Comment: what about if instead creating a library I create components like: `$ ng generate component modules/comp-a` and `$ ng generate component modules/comp-b`?

Comment: it depends on your requirements. if the components are to be used only in this project then this is the way to do it. if the components need to be used in multiple projects it's best to extract them to their own library.

Comment: I want to use them like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="comp-a.js"></script>`, `<script type="text/javascript" src="comp-b.js"></script>` in a normal `html` file and not inside an `Angular` project (but of course, after compile them). The usage should be something similar to what I specified on my post above.

Comment: if you want to use them outside of angular projects you don't want angular components.

Comment: if you want generic components that are usable with any framework look into web components https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components

Comment: this might also be of interest (or a possible duplicate) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226449/does-angular2-use-web-components

Answer (score 4):

Two Angular Components in a single Angular Application is what you need.

To demonstrate, lets create a new Angular Application:

```
ng new my-app
```

Go to Angular Application folder:

```
cd my-app
```

Notice the index.html file that has just been created. Common HTML that you mentioned above can reside in this index.html file. Just preserve `<app-root></app-root>` tags and everything else can be replaced as you wish.

Then, create two Angular Components:

```
ng generate component comp1
ng generate component comp2
```

Edit inside app.component.html file so that this Bootstrap Component would wrap these two recently created Angular Components:

app.component.html:

```
<app-comp1></app-comp1>
<app-comp2></app-comp2>
```

Test your Angular Application:

```
ng serve --open
```

You should be seeing something like this:

> comp1 works! comp2 works!

Comment: After that, can I use them like: `<script type="text/javascript" src="comp-a.js"></script>`, `<script type="text/javascript" src="comp-b.js"></script>` in a normal `html` file and not inside an `Angular` project (but of course, after compile them), like to what I specified on my post above?